# Update using stored procedure on each table row using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `<UserChecklist>` with a datatype of `<List>` in my `ListViewModel` which contains properties for retrieving data from my database.

Here is my `ListViewModel`:

```
   public class ListViewModel
   {
        public List<ListViewModel> UserChecklist { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string CheckItem { get; set; }
        public int SelectID { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
   }
```

Note that in my database `ItemID` is the unique row.

Here is an example of my table (edited the rows for simplicity purposes):

[image]

The dropdown contains 3 options and the comment is an input type of textbox.

Here is code for retrieving result from the database on my `UserController`:

```
foreach (var item in db_RIRO.sp_GetUserChecklist(Session["EID"].ToString()))
{
    vm.UserChecklist.Add(new ListViewModel()
            {
                ItemID = item.ItemID,
                CheckItem = item.CheckItem,
                CheckID = item.CheckID,
                Comments = item.Comments
            });
}
```

And finally here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateUserForm
    @UserID INT,
    @ItemID INT,
    @CheckID INT,
    @Comments VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE tblUser_Checklist 
    SET CheckID = @CheckID, 
        Comments = @Comments
    WHERE ItemID = @ItemID AND UserID = @UserID;
END
GO
```

Unfinished pseudocode that I haven't tried:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateForm (ListViewModel lstviewodel)
{
  foreach(var item in vm.UserChecklist)
  {
    // update each row
  }
}
```

What I want to do is update each row on the my table and execute a stored procedure on each row. How do I do this?

Comment: See `Entity Framework Code First Insert, Update, and Delete Stored Procedures (EF6 onwards)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Why even used a SP for that? Something like `context.UserChecklist.Where(u => u.ItemId == myItemId && u.UserId == myUserId).ToList().ForEach(u => { u.CheckId = myCheckId; u.Comments = myComments;})` would work just fine.